# Flutter: Spacing between widgets NOT margins

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to space the second profile picture (nr 2 on the drawing) to the right of the card without using margin because the first "Test" can differ in length and when it does it'll not render because the profile picture is out of reach of the card. I also want to set the "2km" right next to it.

[What I want it to become - IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWYhp.png)

I have tried every main, cross alignment there is.

```
class _mainlistpage extends State<mainlist> {
  @override
  // TODO: implement widget
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dummyData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                              child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/Profile Picture.png",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text("Test"),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.check_circle,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  size: 20,
                                ),
                                Text("2km"),

                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text("Testtt"),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text("Testtt"),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                              child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/Profile Picture.png",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ]),
            )));
  }
}
```

I want to have the second profile picture to the right of the card but nothing is working. I also want the "2km" text right next to it.

Comment: [Spacer (Flutter Widget of the Week) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FJgd7QN1zI)

Comment: @ejabu, Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Use Expanded to Move Image to the right

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded( // Wrap Second Row with Expanded
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column( ..
          Column( ..
          // Column( .. Move out Last Column that contains Second Image
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/flower-2.jpeg",
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
),
```

[image: Result]

Therefore, currently we have new two section. **Left and Right**.

To put, `2km` beside second image, we can **focus** modifying on **Right Section**

### 2. Replace Column with Row to add more content in right section

Previously we have this :

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/flower-2.jpeg",
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Modify into these lines :

```dart
Row( // change Column to Row
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // will place 2km on TOP
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("2km"),
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/flower-2.jpeg",
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image: Result]

### Fully working code

You can check it in this [Github Repo](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/l_screen/list_view_two_image.dart)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Didn't know about the "Expanded" widget. A million thanks, been working on this problem for 3 days.

Comment: ejabu, can I add you in some way?